# How to reload a model with additional query params?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have model which `has_many` trains.
After clicking some button I want to reload these trains, but I want each reloading request to be sent with additional query parameters.

Now I have something like this:

`this.get('model.trains').forEach(function(train) {train.reload()});`

which sends `trains/:id` requests, but would like it to send something like `trains/:id?class=1`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass [`adapterOptions` to `reload` method](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.12/classes/Model/methods/reload?anchor=reload). That one is available on the 
[`DS.Snapshot`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.12/classes/Snapshot/properties/adapterOptions?anchor=adapterOptions) passed to your application's adapter. You need to extend your application adapter to map the adapter option to a query param on the request.